# WebStorm can't link images from other directory

Tags: html, image, webstorm

I have tried using Express, inside WebStorm, where I have a sample html file, with this content

```
<h2>About</h2>
<img src="/public/img/download.jpg" alt="picture">
```

this does not appear to be working, with a folder directory like this

[image]

Does anybody know why the image can't load properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you mean saying that the images are not loaded? is it about paths resolving in IDE or in browser?

`public` is marked as *Resource* root, so that the paths are resolved relative to it. To have the IDE resolve paths like `"/public/img/download.jpg"`, you need to mark a parent folder of `public` as *Resource* root.

If you have a problem loading your image in browser, it's an issue with the web server being used. Leading slash in URL tells the browser to resolve the URL from web server root. If the server can handle URLs like `<server address>/public/img/download.jpg`, image will be loaded, otherwise 404 error will be thrown